# LocationCallback onLocationResult isn't getting called when device GPS is turned on after initializing LocationCallback

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have a foreground service which gets initialized on start of the app and runs even when the app is destroyed. I have initialized LocationCallback inside my foreground service as shown below:

```
new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

            // My custom code
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
        }
```

I have 2 cases:

a) When the service (along with LocationCallback) is initialized after the device GPS is turned on, things work as expected. That is, control enters into "onLocationResult" after a given duration.

b) But, when service (along with LocationCallback) is initialized before device GPS is turned on, the control never enters into "onLocationResult". Even when the foreground service is running and GPS on device gets turned on (after initialization of LocationCallback).

Can someone help me out in resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs only on an emulator (unsure of what the cause is). If I try to debug on a device (using USB debugging), things are working as expected.